# How to change the default program run under zsh?

Tags: zsh, aws-sam

I have two versions of [AWS SAM CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-install.html) installed on my MacOS. I got the following result when running `where sam` in [zsh](https://www.zsh.org/):

```
$ where sam  
/Users/MyName/.pyenv/shims/sam
/usr/local/bin/sam
```

When running `sam` command, MacOS runs the `sam` under `/Users/MyName/.pyenv/shims/`.

Is it possible to configure my zsh terminal so that `sam` runs the version under `/usr/local/bin`?

The reason I want to do this is that `/Users/MyName/.pyenv/shims/sam` returns an error after I execute it.

I'd like to avoid this problem by running the `sam` under `/usr/local/bin/`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to override `PATH` lookup is to create an alias:

```
alias sam=/usr/local/bin/sam
```

The alias will get priority, so `/usr/local/bin/sam` will be run instead of whichever executable comes first in `PATH` lookup.

You could also make `/usr/local/bin` come first in `PATH`:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

But then you might want other programs in `/Users/MyName/.pyenv/shims` to have still have priority, in which case the alias would be better.